# mxmlc compiles without error but shows blank screen

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flashdevelop

I have followed tut here
http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/as3withmxmlc/
and compiled with flex3.6 and flex4.6 but running swf gives a blank screen. Same program compiled with FDT 5 http://fdt.powerflasher.com/ and runs fine. So what's missing in the command line ?

Update: command line I used is just

```
mxmlc "c:\flextutorial\HelloWorld.as"
```

the same as in the tutorial above.

Update 2: It doesn't run either with FlashDevelop ( http://www.flashdevelop.org/ ). But why it does with FDT 5 ( http://fdt.powerflasher.com ) ?

My source code of HelloWorld.as

```
package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class HelloWorld extends Sprite {

        public function HelloWorld() {
            var display_txt:TextField = new TextField();
            //display_txt.x = 0;
            //display_txt.y = 0;
            display_txt.text = "Hello World!";
            //display_txt.backgroundColor = 0xFF0000;
            addChild(display_txt);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure HelloWorld is the baseclass?

Comment: @weltraumpirat I updated

Comment: @Dunlap Sorry I'm beginner I don't understand what you do mean.

Comment: @user310291  It runs with FDT, because FDT automatically adds all the necessary dependencies to the mxmlc command. If you're using the content debugger plugin (you should), there should be an error message.  Please post it - that should give us a hint on what the exact problem is.

Comment: @weltraumpirat I'm beginner I don't know how to use content debugger plugin, can't someone just copy and paste my code instead ?

Comment: The content debugger plugin is just another version of Flash Player - download here: http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html  It will show error messages and include line numbers and stack traces. No matter who solves your problem, you're going to need it.

Answer (score 1):

When you say running the SWF, can you embed it in a HTML page and view both on the same browser? You could be using 2 flash player versions (one inside the FD IDE and the other)..

Also install the Flash Debugger Player
http://wwww.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html